# 'o' in macOS date format for menu bar clock

Tags: macos, menu-bar, system-settings, time, clock

I have a  problem with clock in menu bar date format. I'd like to show my clock with weekday, and 24 hour. For some reason, I see `Niedz. 13.08 o   19:19` (pl_PL locale). While trying to figure out what is going, I found that the date format in defaults `com.apple.menuextra.clock` set to `"EEE d.MM 'o'  HH:mm"`.

Could you help me to explain this `'o'` and how to change the date format to  the just `"EEE d.MM HH:mm"` (without this `o`)?

I've tried to write defaults and kill `SystemUIServer`, `Dock`, `com.apple.dock.extra` without any luck

Comment: Are you talking about the clock to the right of the menu bar? What is your Mac model exactly and macOS? Pls update your question to include these.

Comment: Yes, in menu bar

Comment: What did you do to find "that the date format in defaults com.apple.menuextra.clock set to "EEE d.MM 'o'  HH:mm"? Which format is set in System Settings?

Comment: In addition to what @nohillside has said about checking your time and date format in system settings, make sure to check under localisation settings  which can be found at `System settings`>`General`>`Language & region`>`Advanced`. Here you can change the time and date format to short, medium, long, full lengths, which may show up that `\`o\`` that's been added to your time and date format

Comment: @AVelj thank you, I've checked the formats and there's no `o` there. My worry is also about that I can't really change the format. Even I've changed it and `defauls read` shows new format, time is still in the same format.

Comment: Did you try to change it in System Settings, and reboot afterwards?

Comment: Changes in System Settings/Preferences changes format back to the original and updates clock as well. Changing in plist file directly with or without reboot seems to do nothing